# RubyMine debugger error

Tags: ruby, rubymine

i'm using RubyMine 6.3 buth I have some problems with debugger

> C:\Ruby200\bin\ruby.exe -e
>   $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift)
>   C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.23.beta1/bin/rdebug-ide
>   --disable-int-handler --port 49883 --dispatcher-port 49884 -- C:/Ruby200/Projekty/123/test
>   C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require': cannot load such file -- debase_internals (LoadError)  from
>   C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`
>   require'     from
>   C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/debase-0.0.9/lib/debase.rb:4:in
>   `<top (required)>'    from
>   C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`
>   require'     from
>   C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require'     from
>   C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.23.beta1/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:8:in`
>   '    from
>   C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.23.beta1/bin/rdebug-ide:8:in
>   `require_relative'    from
>   C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.23.beta1/bin/rdebug-ide:8:in`
>   '    from -e:1:in `load'     from -e:1:in`'
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

But when use Ruby Interactive Console, all is working. When I use Komodo IDE all is fine.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How i can repair that problem ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I fixed my issue by installing `debase` manually from the terminal, not from the one bundled with rubymine, try it

```
gem install debase
```

PS: I was using ruby 1.9.3

Comment: I just tried and got `No source for ruby-2.1.2-p95 provided with debugger-ruby_core_source gem.`, I'll look into it.

Comment: well I guess i should have mentioned that I was using ruby 1.9.3 for that project, I haven't had any problems with ruby 2.1.2

Comment: I always remove debugger gem from gemfile (temporarily) when i need to debug with rubymine, debugger is just there for my coworkers

Comment: I am using Ruby 2.0.0 and this doesnt work for me sadly

Comment: well you can also try `gem install ruby-debug-ide`

Comment: This helped me too

Answer (score 8):

Adding the following to my Gemfile made debugging and rails commands work (versions: Rubymine 7.0.4, ruby 2.3.1 and rails 4.2.6):

```
  group :development do
    gem 'ruby-debug-ide', '0.4.24'
    gem 'debase', '0.2.1'
  end
```

Answer (score 3):

Just spent 6 hours working through this, and just in case this helps others, here is what I did:

1. Upgraded to latest version of RubyMine (downloaded 7.0 from JetBrains site)
2. Upgraded to Ruby 2.1.2
3. Opened RubyMine > File > Default Settings > Ruby SDK & Gems > Selected ruby-2.1.2 > Clicked '+' on right hand side > Installed cucumber and calabash-cucumber
4. RubyMine > Run > Edit Configurations > changed the SDK to ruby-2.1.2

And it worked.  Hopefully this might help others new to Calabash / Ruby / RubyMine

Comment: Thanks for this! I had changed my default SDK, but didn't realize I had to change the SDK in the "Edit Configurations..." box too. Using the "Project SDK" didn't work and I had to switch it to "Other SDK"

Answer (score 0):

```
Martins-MacBook-Pro:~ martincleaver$ sudo gem install debase -v 0.0.9
Password:
ERROR:  Error installing debase:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
checking for vm_core.h... no
    No source for ruby-2.0.0-p648 provided with debugger-ruby_core_source gem.

Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details. 

$ more /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/debase-0.0.9/ext/gem_make.out
checking for vm_core.h... no
Makefile creation failed
Check the mkmf.log file for more details

$ more /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/debase-0.0.9/ext/mkmf.log 
have_header: checking for vm_core.h... -------------------- no

conftest.c:3:10: fatal error: 'vm_core.h' file not found
#include <vm_core.h>

--------------------
```

https://github.com/denofevil/debase/issues/9 tracks the issue from the gem standpoint. It's the best place to discuss the matter.

That said, iheggie's answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/37086441/722034 worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Updating Rubymine to the latest version (and waiting for reindexing to finish, which can be quite long) helped fix some problems cf https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360009522340-Unable-to-use-debugger-debase-0-3-0-beta34-install-error-